# How do you interpret an "interrogative word + non-polite form + か + 知る" construct?

Tags: syntax, questions, particle-か

Came across this sentence that has this "interrogative word + non-polite form + か + 知る" structure but not too sure if this is a kind of question or answer.

> どこの会議室か知りません。

Is this a question or an answer?

Am I right to assume that this sentence simply means:

> Do you know what kind of meeting room (is that)?

Comment: The pattern and the example don't match. (unless you mean non-polite form of a noun?). Which pattern do you want?

Comment: @virmaior It looks like they mean Ｎだ＋か with だ omitted.

Comment: @snailboat ahh, I think you're right. It's been a while since I thought of that construction in a way that one would wind up parsing it like that, but I guess that makes sense if your main thought of か is question-maker.

Answer (score 0):

> どこの会議室か知りません。

Literally means "I don't know which meeting room it is."

> Do you know what kind of meeting room (that is)?

Would literally be (それが)どんな会議室か知っていますか。